# Solidity Contract Size and ERC721

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721

I have a contract that mints Tokens and I’m currently managing the properties of these Tokens using a series of Arrays, as follows:

```
uint256[] public tokenIDsArray;    
uint256[] public tokenETHPricesArray;
uint256[] public tokenSushiPricesArray;
string[] public tokenURIsArray;
```

I never planned on having this many Arrays in my contract (it started as a quickie “test” project and it’s ballooned since) - so I’m now thinking it’d be ***much*** better to convert everything to this:

```
// Create a struct to manage all the Token's properties:  
struct MyToken {
   uint256 tokenID;    
   uint256 priceInETH;
   uint256 priceInSushi;
   string tokenURI;   
}

// Declare a single Array of these struct-objects:
MyToken[] public myTokensArray;
```

So not only will I be working with a single array as opposed to 4 arrays, but I could easily add more properties to my struct without having to create another Array for each new property.

Seems like a no brainer, but I'm really curious and would love to know if:

1. Will converting everything to the “struct way” really actually save a lot of memory and reduce the Contract’s size significantly? Or do structs actually take up even more memory in Solidity for some strange reason? (I know Solidity is kinda finicky so I'm never surprised when things are weird with it.)
2. Is there a quick way/tool to find out just how much memory this will save me? At least approximately?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can test this out using https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-contract-sizer

Comment: I already did. The Struct way produced a BIGGER size contract... Makes no sense to me.